# Setting up Pi AP getting errors

Tags: raspbian, pi-3

So I'm trying to setup my RasPi 3 to become a wireless AP while also being connected to the wireless internet at a hotel.  I've been following a few sites to set this up.

But i'm getting this -
`no address range available for DHCP request via wlan0`

ok
Here is my /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet manual

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
    address 10.192.168.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 10.192.168.0
    broadcast 10.192.168.255
    hostapd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf

#    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.ipv4.nat
```

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo cat /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf

```
interface=wlan0
hw_mode=g
channel=6
auth_algs=1
wpa=2
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=CCMP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
wpa_passphrase=test123
ssid=vaca
```

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo cat /etc/dnsmasq.conf

```
interface=wlan0
dhcp-range=10.192.168.50,10.192.168.200,255.255.255.0,12h
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: I think we are going to need more details on the configuration and software components you are using.

Comment: updated.  sorry!

Comment: try `dhcp-range=wlan0,10.192.168.50,10.192.168.200,255.255.255.0,12h`

Comment: Nope that didn't help.

Comment: I take that back.  It DID work.  I just have no internet.